# Increasing mysql import size

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a mysql file to my cpanel phpmyadmin. But I am getting this error message. "#1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes"

I have tried putty as well. But the error message is same. I don't know how to change the mox upload size in mysql in cpanel.

Please help me

Thank you so much

Comment: file size is around 4.6mb if that is sql.gz

Comment: if just .sql then the size is 46mb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with the php.ini, its clearly an error message from the DBMS.

You can increase the value of the max_allowed_packet in the my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 128M
```

After restarting your mysqld it should work (for larger data increase the value more)

If you try to "import with putty", i guess your are using mysql from command line, in this case you can start mysql with the --max_allowed_packet parameter e.g:

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=128M -u root -p sampledb < dump.sql
```

Alternatively if you source the file from within a running mysql session you can set the parameter by:

```
set global max_allowed_packet=128M;
```

last example only is effective till next restart of mysqld, for a permanent solution stick to my first example.

Comment: Yes You are correct. It is not a problem with php.ini. How do i locate this my.cnf file?

Comment: I tried this mysql --max_allowed_packet=128M -u root -p sampledb < dump.sql example. But the error message is same :(

Comment: @the my.cnf file is usually in /etc/ on linux systems. Can you do the following in mysql: show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'? As which user you connect to the database?

Answer (score 3):

php -i | grep php.ini

Open the Loaded php.ini and modify  "upload_max_filesize" and restart Apache (assuming u have apache)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have Apache. But all those are in cpanel? I mean php.ini and restarting options?

Comment: @user1080319 if you using shared hosting, that can be the problem to change that settings.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to increase the MySQL daemon’s max_allowed_packet. You can do this to a running daemon by logging in as Super and running the following commands.

```
# mysql -u admin -p

mysql> set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then to import your dump:

```
gunzip < dump.sql.gz | mysql -u admin -p database
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting these values in `php.ini` solved my problem:

```
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
php_admin_value max_input_time 360
```